# What is the method to check if the target of a symlink exists or not?

Tags: c, linux

Using a c program I need to find and delete all symbolic links in a directory, with missing target.

What is the most efficient way to check whether the target of a symbolic link exist or not. Any method other than opening the symlink and check the return value. I'm working with linux and gcc.

Comment: What about `stat()`? Symlinks are resolved at OS/FS level so you don't need to worry about manually finding out the target, unless you want to access the symlink file itself.

Comment: Why would you do this in C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm developing a C application in linux. And I need to create a symlink for all files the user uploads and delete them when the files are removed.

Answer (score 1):

The `access ()` function with `F_OK` mode set will follow a symlink path.

The following code will print "Yes!" if both the symlink and the target file exist...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (void)
{
    if (access ("test.txt", F_OK) != -1) {
        puts ("Yes!");
        return 0;
    }

    puts ("No.");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [`access`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html), or indeed [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). That's about all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

From the `man 3 stat` man page

> If  the named file is a symbolic link, the stat() function shall continue pathname resolution using the
>          contents of the symbolic link, and shall return information pertaining to the  resulting  file  if  the
>          file exists.

So the following works nice:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct stat ctx;
  int status = stat("test.txt", &ctx);
  if(status != 0) {
    perror("[stat]");
    return 1;
  }
  else {
      puts("works nice");
  }
  return 0;
}
```